# Video isn't recognized as HDR in YouTube upload

Tags: youtube, nvidia, ms-media-foundation, hdr

After managing to export HDR H.265 video with the Nvidia SDK I am trying to push to YouTube.
[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zT-wH6PdU-ZQcchFn1SEoZpXYP3cpXsC/view?usp=drive_link) is a direct link to the video and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K23AFdya2Ps) is the YouTube link, a simple 1 second green screen.

YouTube [says](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7126552?hl=en) that I need to have certain metadata in the file, so I used [their tool](https://github.com/youtubehdr/hdr_metadata) to inject it. With MediaInfo I got this:

[image]

and yet my video doesn't show as HDR in YouTube.

[This link](https://4kmedia.org/lg-new-york-hdr-uhd-4k-demo/) has also a New York HDR file. When I upload the very same file into YouTube it isn't shown as HDR.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhCXz0Wayok) YouTube video shows correctly as HDR and when I grab it and send it to mediainfo it has similar metadata:

[image]

but when I upload it myself to YouTube it isn't showing as HDR.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested.
The metadata must be present in the *codec*, not in the container.
Therefore, the way to achieve this via NvEnc is to include the "Color Description" flags as follows:

```
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.videoSignalTypePresentFlag = 1;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.videoFormat = NV_ENC_VUI_VIDEO_FORMAT_UNSPECIFIED;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.videoFullRangeFlag = 0;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.colourDescriptionPresentFlag = 1;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.colourPrimaries = NV_ENC_VUI_COLOR_PRIMARIES_BT2020;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.transferCharacteristics = NV_ENC_VUI_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_SMPTE2084;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.colourMatrix = NV_ENC_VUI_MATRIX_COEFFS_BT2020_NCL;
```